# Struts2 ActionSupport getTexts() is not work

Tags: java, struts2

My Web-program config is Struts2 and Tomcat 6.0.

and my project is support i18n(International~)

and I use class extends `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport`.

The `getText(String)` method works, but `getTexts()` doesn't work.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    public void textString() {
        // print "en" works
        String strTemp1 = getText("CURRENT.LOCALE");
        System.out.println(strTemp1);

        // This doesn't; bundle is null.
        ResourceBundle bundle = getTexts();
        System.out.println(bundle);
    }
}
```

`globalMessage_en.properties`

```
CURRNET.LOCALE = en
```

Comment: can you give details as how you accessing that.generally getTexts() Get the resource bundle associated with the implementing class (usually an action).

Comment: Is the misspelling of `CURRENT.LOCALE` in the property file a typo? Also, how are you declaring the global message resources in your S2 config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually works as intended. From the [docs of `TextProvider.getTexts()`](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/TextProvider.html#getTexts%28java.lang.String%29)):

> Get the resource bundle associated with the implementing class (usually an action).

As you only have a global message resource, it returns `null`. If you would have a specific message resource for your action (e.g. `MyAction.properties` in the same directory as your action), it would return a corresponding `ResourceBundle` (`PropertyResourceBundle`).